# Azure DevOps - How to Invoke get commits rest api

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

How do I invoke the azure devops rest api's get commits rest method using the az devops invoke command?

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?api-version=7.0
```

I’m mostly confused about where to specify the “/commits” at the end. What part of the url anatomy does fall into? I can't pass it to az devops invoke as a resource or query-parameters argument.

From my notes:
[image]

If I attempt to invoke the following I only get repository information back, not the commits. I tried changing the resource to commits and I got the same response back.

```
az devops invoke --route-parameters project=XXXX --area git --resource repositories --query-parameters repositoryid=####
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below steps:

```
az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/<Organization Name>
az devops invoke --area git --resource commits --route-parameters project=<Project Name> repositoryId=<Repository Name> --http-method GET
```

It works on my side:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I got it working with your example. I was adding repositoryId to the query parameters instead of the route parameters.